# How to print only once per execution in Python

Tags: python, f-string

I'm not a very experienced programmer, and I tried to find a library that contained a Python function that would print something only the first time this function was called from the same call and no more per script execution. Because I didn't find it, I created my own, and it works. But I don't know how to make it able to work just like print(f'') so I can include variables. Loops+break won't work here.

This is how it looks right now:

```
#dictionary so we don't have scope issues
already_printed = {}
def print_only_once(msg):
    try:
        testing = already_printed[msg]
    except KeyError:
        already_printed[msg] = msg
        print(msg)
    return
```

And I call it using:

```
print_only_once('my special message')
```

If this message has been printed before, it won't print again. I would like to be able to also do something like this:

```
print_only_once(f'temp is {var1} and humidity is {var2}')
```

And this special message would print only one time per script execution, regardless of how many times it was called, including with differente values for var1 and/or var2 from the first call.

Any help? Maybe there's something that does exactly that out there but I couldn't find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The format string is expanded before the resulting string is ever sent to your `print_only_once` function. So within the scope of your function, only specific already printed strings are ignored.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0501/ would work for this scenario, but sadly it is deferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this when you format the string in the caller, because your function only receives the formatted string.

You need to have your function take the format string and values separately. Then you can save the format string in your dictionary, and call `.format()` explicitly.

```
already_printed = set()
def print_only_once(format_string, *args, **kwargs):
    if format_string not in already_printed:
        print(format_string.format(*args, **kwargs))
        already_printed.add(format_string)

print_only_once('temp is {var1} and humidity is {var2}', var1=var1, var2=var2)
```

Comment: thanks mate! there's a typo inside the print, but I get what you did

Comment: I changed the name of the parameter while writing the answer, but missed one of them. SO needs an IDE. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this:

```
already_printed = []


def print_only_once(msg_name, msg):
    if msg_name not in already_printed:
        already_printed.append(msg_name)
        print(msg)
    return
```

I added another parameter called "msg_name". You should write what the message is about in there (like giving a group name). And you write your actual text/message in "msg".

Comment: An improvement to this is instead of using an unordered list for storing and searching O(n) (where n is the size of the list), use an ordered (sorted) list O(log n) (though this would degrade to O(n) due to the way a list insertion is performed) or a hash table O(1). Searching an unordered list would be very slow. If we already printed 1 million messages, then that means that every time we try to print another, we would iterate across each and every item of that 1 million messages searching for the message. Calling it just 3 times would require you to iterate a maximum of 3 million items :)